# What should I use as a memory barrier for a Collection?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, memory-barriers, memory-fences

Say I have a Java `ArrayList`, which obviously cannot be a `volatile` variable (`volatile` in the sense of: all of its internal variables are `volatile`), and want to see its latest state in a second thread, given I can be sure the second thread is executed after the first thread *ended* (a first thread which may have modified the `ArrayList` instance).

Using a [Memory Barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier) this should be easy. But how can I construct such a memory barrier that affects all internal member variables/states of the `ArrayList` instance? I know that synchronizing is an option, but I do not know on which object I should synchronize to achieve the desired effect.

**Is there any official reference on this problem, defining a best practice?**

The most straightforward way of achieving a memory barrier seems to me calling something like [`fullFence()`](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/171). But it seems like this is not the recommended way ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Synchronizing works as long as you synchronize on the same object when reading and writing, it is guaranteed to be consistent. I recommend picking up Java Concurrency In Practic for an indepth dive into concurrency.

In your case, then end of a thread provides a memory barrier so it should be safe to read any values that may have been modified by the first thread. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html.

```
The final action in a thread T1 synchronizes-with any action in another thread T2 that detects that T1 has terminated.

T2 may accomplish this by calling T1.isAlive() or T1.join().
```

Comment: Given I have Scala `Future {...}.onComplete {...}` callback in my code (the `onComplete` callback is called when the `Future`'s thread ends, and in the `onComplete` callback the second thread is started by a second `Future`: Is it true that the callback is called _after_ the first `Future`'s thread ends, or is it called _before_ it ends?

Answer (score 1):

> I can be sure the second thread is executed after the first thread ended

Let's call your two threads A and B, where thread B is the one that produced a result, and thread A is the longer-running one that wants to use the result.

Your A thread only needs to call `B.join()`.  Everything thread B wrote to memory before it died is guaranteed to become visible to thread A after the `join()` call returns.

---

Another approach would be to protect the data in question with a lock.  If thread B writes data while holding the lock, then thread A will be guaranteed to see the data after B has released the lock and A acquires it.

---

A third approach is to use a `volatile` variable.  You say that the data in question can not be declared `volatile`, but accessing a volatile variable affects more than just the variable itself.  If thread B updates the data and then updates some `volatile int i;` Then everything B wrote to memory before updating `i` will become visible to A after A reads `i`.

Answer (score 1):

What you really need is happens-before on list. Full-fence in the end of state update doesn't guarantee that reader will see consistent, fully updated values in list, e.g. because some reads will stuck in core [invalidation queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol) or because JIT will cache some values in registers, because VM doesn't know that you are dealing with shared data, so code can behave not the way you expect. If you are not afraid of JIT (maybe because you know you are re-reading list from memory some way), then full-fence will be enough only on x86 architecture, because x86 has TSO (total store order) property, so barriers (~fences) needed to read shared data (LoadLoad and LoadStore) are [actually no-ops](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html). But fences and barriers are not the part of JMM or any public API, so they are not available for us (except Unsafe). As long as JMM gives you correctness guarantees only for [well-formed execution](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.7) (using happens-before and synchronized-with relations) you should rely on this mechanics, not tricky Unsafe.

To provide happens-before relationship without synchronization you can add additional volatile variable and write in it in the end of update and read from it before reading from list (writing to volatile variable happens before reading written value from this variable). Or you can simple synchronize on your list instance with the same effect (releasing of monitor happens before acquiring the same monitor) + mutual exclusion.